# Plural of "an end in itself"

Tags: grammatical-number

In singular English say:

> The thing is an end in itself.

How does plural look like then?

> The things are the ends in themselves.

Am I right?

Comment: When you use an indefinite article in the singular, there is no need to change to a definite article in the plural. The plural of the indefinite article is a zero article: a house => houses, an apple, apples.

Comment: I think it's General Reference that the things themselves can be self-justifying [individually or collectively](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+an+end+in+themselves%2Care+ends+in+themselves&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Care%20an%20end%20in%20themselves%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20ends%20in%20themselves%3B%2Cc0), and anyone who's thinking of using ***the*** definite article in either context should be asking questions on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), not here.

Comment: OK, I didn't notice English Language Learners at StackExchange before.

Comment: [Please ‘never’ use   on ELU, ELL, or other non-coding Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4722).

Comment: Usage: http://www.google.ca/search?q=%22are+ends+in+themselves%22 -> About 28,700 results; http://www.google.ca/search?q=%22are+an+end+in+themselves%22 -> About 188,000 results; and sometimes both appear in the same work: http://www.google.ca/search?q=%22end+in+themselves%22+%22ends+in+themselves%22 -> About 152,000 results

Answer (score 14):

It's done like this as well:
*Peace, love and understanding **are ends in themselves**, and Mr. Costello is to be commended for advocating them.*

Comment: *Similar but different.* This is an answer to a different question.

Answer (score 6):

*The things are **an end** in themselves.* -- ('respectively' being understood.)

Comment: Isn't that ambiguous between whether they're a single collective end or each is an individually an end?

Comment: Contrast: Peace, love and understanding are an end in themselves. (single collective end)

Comment: Killing badgers, kissing babies and defrauding the public  are an end in themselves (multiple individual ends)

Comment: It's clear from context in my examples, but it isn't clear grammatically.

Comment: Similarly: John and Marsha are an item. A toothbrush and a can are items.

Comment: I am little bit confused. Why are John and Maria only an item and not items? Where is difference between single collective end and multiple individual ends?

Answer (score 3):

*These things are ends in themselves* -- if each 'thing' being referred to is itself an individual end.

*The things are an end in themselves* -- if the 'things' are collectively an end.